# Need to navigate to a particular folder on the cmd

Tags: command-line, command

I need to navigate to `C:\Users\csf10dum\Desktop\dex2jar-0.0.9.15`  , but I don't know how to do it.  read numerous articles but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your windows >> navigate to your Command Line window  then :

1: Type "PWD" This Will tell you what directory are you in now.
2: If let's say when you typed 'PWD' you saw `C:\Users\`
from there you will have to write
     `C:\Users\ cd csf10dum`

and this will take you to

```
 C:\Users\csf10dum
```

Then you type

```
  C:\Users\csf10dum\ cmd Desktop
```

and so on

Comment: this was perfect, I was away from my computer for a while there but this has done the job

Answer (score 0):

try typing "cd " then drag the folder into the cmd window? its the easiest way if you need to use commands in that folder.